# Optimize-VHD not found or deleted

Tags: docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I have WSL2 enabled. I am trying to shrink Docker disk using

```
Optimize-VHD -Path $Env:LOCALAPPDATA\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx -Mode Full
```

But I am getting error:

```
Optimize-VHD : Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'XXXXX' because the object was not
found. The object might have been deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is runnin
g.
At line:1 char:1
+ Optimize-VHD -Path .\ext4.vhdx -Mode Full
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Optimize-VHD], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ObjectNotFound,Microsoft.Vhd.PowerShell.Cmdlets.OptimizeVhd
```

Comment: This is good info, but I didn't notice it was here on Stack Overflow at first.  Unfortunately it's not on-topic here. Would you consider reposting on Super User? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reconstruct Windows vm file.
Run as admin:

```
mofcomp.exe %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof
```